# PHP only provide one specific parameter among many with default value

Tags: php, function, methods, parameters

```
<?php

class klasa {
    public function funkcja($x = 'default', $y = 'value')
    {
        var_dump($x);
        var_dump($y);
    }
}

$x = new klasa;
$x->funkcja('other value');
```

[image]

As on the picture, how to omit first parameter which has his default value and only affect second one?

I tried `$x->funkcja(NULL, 'other value');` doesn't work, `$x->funkcja(, 'other value');` doesn't work too.

How to achieve it?

Comment: From the [PHP Documentation](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) `Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected`... if you absolutely have to do this, consider passing one argument comprising an associative array; but you'll have to handle the differences in your function code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible answers. Basically, check if value is null and then assign a default value.

```
class klasa {
    public function funkcja($x, $y = 'value')
    {
        $x = ($x === null ? 'default' : $x);

        var_dump($x);
        var_dump($y);
    }
}

$x = new klasa;
$x->funkcja(null, 'value');
```

---

`$x === null` - Check if `$x` is null
`?`
`'default'` - If it's **true** assign a default value
`:`
`$x` - If it's **not true** reassign it's value